# Vue or Vuetify folder select

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In my app I need the user to select a folder, then the directory path is taken and used as a string elsewhere.
Is there a relatively simple way to have a folder selector?
I'm using vuetify at the moment and had the below when I was looking for a file to upload

```
<v-file-input
      prepend-icon="mdi mdi-paperclip"
      ref="filepath"
      label="Filepath"
      :error-messages="filepathErrors"
      hint="The filepath for the file to be processed"
      required
 ></v-file-input>
```

Then I just use the ref where I need it.
Is there a simple way I can change this to a folder input?

Comment: With the current HTML spec (and browser implementations) it is only possible to select a file - but not a folder. And the File object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) only exposes the filename but not the path/folder.

Answer (score 0):

vuetify sends the props to the underlying input. If you are using webkit, you can do

```
<v-file-input webkitdirectory>
```

That will work in chrome and electron, but not in all/older browsers